# Would Ruby on Rails suit my work..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to make a web site with the following basic features- (1)**User registration for buyers and sellers.** (2)**profile pages** (3)**A buyer should be able to post work and should get profile links** of the corresponding seller who has expertise in that work.

As time progresses i would want to add more features to the site.The **freelancer sites where user can post jobs and get bids is the best example** of the work.

(1)I want my code to be **maintainable** as i woud be adding features later on. (2)It should be **quick to develop**. (3)**Resources should be available**(not the entire thing, atleast in bits and pieces) for the above requirements and should not be tough to find for future enhancements. (4)**Design should be decoupled from the buisness logic** as i would outsource the design work.

I was thinking of Ruby on Rails for this work as i have experience in the MVC model and RoR looks cool.I am from the mobility domain so i don't know whether RoR will suit my work

Would RoR suit this purpose.If yes where can i find the resources to the above mentioned requirements.

Thanks

Comment: If you are new to RoR I'd suggest you to try some things out, like building a very simple blog or Twitter clone.

Comment: People, please note that this is **NOT** a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4889248! Just in case. :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Radek.The twitter app would help me in learning on profile creation.This rhymes with my work.I guess this should get me started with it -http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/creating-a-twitter-clone-in-rails-part-1/ .Thanks a lot Radek !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails would be ideal for this type of website.

Check out some of these resources for info on how to use Ruby on Rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

http://railscasts.com/

http://www.railsforum.com/

I noticed you are already aware of TeachMeToCode, but there is a tag there for all the Rails 3 tutorials, with some blog tutorials and what looks like the beginning of a series on how to build a del.icio.us clone.  Since they are in Rails 3, they would be well worth checking out:

http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/tag/rails-3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will go ahead with rails for this project.I am planning to use the "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorials" book to start with.I will be using the resources that you have mentioned along with it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tutorials:

http://railsforzombies.org

It will let you have your own point of view quickly.

Comment: This is one really different way of learning.Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on with which languages you have experience. Any good MVC framework will do the job just fine but if you like Ruby syntax RoR is definitely a good framework to develop this kind of application.

Comment: sorta disagree with the first bit. There is a HUGE amount of difference between mvc frameworks. Productivity between something like java structs vs rails is not even comparable (as an example)

Comment: Depends on what your preferences are but I agree that for this kind of app some more light-weight framework would be best.